# Android: View.Gone not working for AutoCompleteTextview as ExposedDropdownMenu

Tags: android, kotlin, autocompletetextview, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I have an `ExposedDropDownMenu` as a Spinner as recommended from Material.IO. My problem is that, `View.Gone` does not work and leaves an arrow in the view and therefore still occupies space.

### Screenshot

[image: View not gone]

### XML

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/calibrate_message_dropdown_menu_TWO"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="none"
    tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

### Code

```
calibrate_message_dropdown_menu_TWO.visibility = View.GONE
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try hiding the TextInputLayout instead of the contained AutoCompleteTextView. Add an id for the outer TextInputLayout like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:id="@+id/dropdown_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/calibrate_message_dropdown_menu_TWO"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="none"
    tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

and then in code:

```
dropdown_layout.visibility = View.GONE
```

Comment: Oh wow, that did worked. I'm surprised, because I did try this before and it didn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the dropdown icon just use:

```
textInputLayout.endIconMode = TextInputLayout.END_ICON_NONE
```

[image]

Comment: Nah, I want to remove the entire layout, not only the arrow.